# How can I update my Eclipse installation (e..g overcome the "annot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found" error)?

Tags: eclipse, updates, eclipse-juno

I’m using Eclipse Juno on Mac 10.9.1 (Java 6).  I’m trying to update my Eclipse installation by clicking the “Help” menu and selecting “Check For Updates”.  However, when I click on the “Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers” checkbox that appears after I see a message “The operation cannot be completed.  See the details:” and all that is displayed in the details are

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
```

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this further and update my Eclipse installation?

Comment: Try reinstalling. Always works for me...

Comment: What are the rest of the details of the error? The answer lies somewhere in what specifically can't be found.